# What's the advantage of session multiplexing in OCI Connection Pooling

Tags: connection-pooling, oracle-call-interface

I am researching on OCI connection pooling whose main advantage is session multiplexing. From what I understand session multiplexing is having multiple sessions over the same physical connection.

After doing some tests I realize that the OCI driver multiplexes multiple sessions over the same physical connection **only when the first session on that connection is IDLE**. While it seems logical to not start a new session when the initial one is already active, I fail to understand the actual use of session multiplexing in an web application.

Won't it be very rare that the application requests for a connection and does not use it (i.e. the borrowed connection remains IDLE)?

It would be great if someone could share their experience in using the session multiplexing feature of OCI connection pooling.

Comment: To be more precise I will reframe my questions
1. At what point does OCI create a new session on the same physical connection
2. Is it true that two sessions on the same physical connection cannot execute concurrently. At the execution time OCI internally figures out this and spawns new physical connection.
3. What does the application benefit from starting a new session on the same physical connection versus starting a new physical connection?l 
4. Are there any disadvantages or side effects in having multiple sessions on the same physical connection.

Comment: By performing some tests I verified that credential verification is still done when a new session is created. The test included getting a connection from the pool with different schema information i.e. username/password. A new session was created on the same physical connection even if the connection was requested with different username/password. The test was done to verify if creating a new session save credential authentication time (which is not the case)

Comment: you can edit you question rather the commenting on it ;)

Answer (score -1):

I found the following link to be quite interesting and it may help shed some light on your question:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/ociconpl.htm

After reading this article, it appears that the connections are created and maintained at the "session" layer of the OSI model. Basically, the "IDLE" connection might be able to run in the background for a process like VoIP or getting information from a DBMS. Wish I could be more help. Please let me know what you find out. Thanks & best wishes!!! Cheers!